# Privatising a public method in a subclass of a base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, virtual-inheritance

I'm working on a class hierarchy structure for graphs in which I have this method called `disjoint_union`. Because the base class contains attributes (like the adjacency list) that need to be updated for all subclasses, I put a method in this class with parameter `graph`, like so:

```
class graph {
    public:
        // ....
        void disjoint_union(const graph& g);
}
```

Two of its subclasses are `ugraph` (undirected graphs) and `dgraph` (directed graphs). The class `dgraph`, needs to update the "in-adjacency" list, i.e., an adjacency list for the in-neighbours of every vertex of the graph. So, I can declare the method `graph::disjoint_union` as virtual and that's the end of the story. But I don't want this class to have the same method (i.e., with the same parameter type) because it would admit undirected graphs. So, my "solution" (not that it really is a problem), is:

```
class dgraph : public graph {
    public:
        // ....
        void disjoint_union(const dgraph& g);
        // ....
    private:
        using graph::disjoint_union;
}
```

If I do something like this:

```
dgraph dG;
// initialise dG
ugraph uG;
// initialise uG
dG.disjoint_union(uG);
```

the compiler issues an error as the only method called `disjoint_union` that can accept a `ugraph` in class `dgraph` is declared private. This need to declare a method as private is just a workaround since I could do something like:

```
graph* dG = new dgraph(); // I know smart pointers should be chosen over raw pointers
// initialise dG
ugraph uG;
// initialise uG
dG.disjoint_union(uG);
```

something that can be regarded as "bad" and that is exacerbated even further for subclasses like rooted trees:

```
class rtree : public dgraph {
    public:
        // ....
        void disjoint_union(const rtree& t);
        // ....
    private:
        using dgraph::disjoint_union;
}
```

which has to update its own attributes after doing such operation. Evidently, a possible implementation of `rtree::disjoint_union` is:

```
void rtree::disjoint_union(const rtree& t) {
    dgraph::disjoint_union(t);
    // update rtree's attributes
}
```

(and likewise in the other classes). Now, C++17 allows this:

```
class graph {
    public:
        // ....
        virtual void disjoint_union(const graph& g);
}
class dgraph : public graph {
    public:
        // ....
        void disjoint_union(const dgraph& g);
        // ....
    private:
        // this time, graph::disjoint_union is not declared as private
        // using graph::disjoint_union;
}
```

but raises several warnings including

```
graph.hpp:113: warning: ‘virtual void graph::disjoint_union(const graph&)’ was hidden [-Woverloaded-virtual]
  113 |   virtual void disjoint_union(const graph& g);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
dgraph.hpp:145: warning: 'dgraph::disjoint_union' hides overloaded virtual function
```

Question: is there a better method to overload the method `disjoint_union`? (better than making methods private) I am concerned that these warnings are telling me that something is not guaranteed like the appropriate method not being called, or that this way of overloading is allowing calls to the `disjoint_union` method of a parent class (which I don't want). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does every child class of `graph` need to implement `disjoint_union`?

Comment: `void dgraph::disjoint_union(const dgraph&);` has not the same parameters than base class, so hides the base class version. we can still call base class implementation with `dG.graph::disjoint_union(uG);`.

Comment: Alright, so privatising seems the way to go... @FantasticMrFox, not every child subclass needs to reimplement. But most of them.

Comment: if you want to disallow `disjoint_union` between `ugraph` and `dgraph`, then that method should probably not be in base class.

Comment: Okay, I put the method in the base class so as not to repeat code. The code that is common to both ```ugraph::disjoint_union``` and ```dgraph::disjoint_union``` (currently in ```graph::disjoint_union```) should be placed in some other function, then.

Comment: Where do you use virtual inheritance?

Comment: I don't think I ever mentioned that, but I do use virtual inheritance. In the full version of the code, the class `rtree` inherits from two classes `dgraph` and `tree`, which both in turn inherit from `graph`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you get this warning because of the signatures `disjoint_unions` methods are different by arguments types.

The best way to resolve this warning is do something like that in the derived class

```
void disjoint_union(const graph& g)
{
    auto* d = dynamic_cast<dgraph*>(&g); // cast to pointer to avoid exceptions
    if (!d) {
        graph::disjoint_union(g);
        return;
    }
    // YOUR CODE IS HERE
}
```

Comment: Right, I used to have this, but as far as I'm concerned ```dynamic_cast``` seems to be slow. I mean, having a parameter with the appropriate type seems best.

Comment: So, your solution is to keep the type ```graph``` and use the dynamic cast. In case the graph's type is not appropriate an exception is raised so the pointer avoids it. But I don't want to do a ```disjoint_union``` with ```ugraph```  and ```dgraph```, so the exception should be fine.

Comment: well, if dynamic_cast is too slow to you, then you can use SFINAE.

Comment: I like the way you think. SFINAE seems very appropriate and although I had used it before I forgot to consider to use it here. But the more I think about your initial solution the more I like it. I'll post an answer to my own question summarising my proposal. I'll mention your post and comments of other users. Although, since yours is the only answer, I'll give credit to you by accepting it. Thank you.